# How can I read / write pixels in a SDL_Surface in SDL2?

Tags: sdl-2

How can I read and write pixel data contained in a SDL_Surface in SDL2? (1)

I tried searching online for a solution to this but didn't find anything which suprised me. I remember it could be done in the SDL 1.2, but I can't find anything relevant to SDL 2.*

*(With the exception of manupulating textures, which isn't what I want to do. The results will be the same but I don't want to edit an object which resides in GPU memory.)

I have an SDL_Surface and I want to manipulate the pixels. The reason I want to do this is because I want to translate all black pixels into white pixels. (2)

I then load the surface into a texture object for rendering.

I wasn't able to find a solution to (2) so I tried a manual approach with (1).

Answer (score 2):

The `SDL_Surface` structure has a field named `pixels` which is an array containing every pixel from left to right, top to bottom, using some pixel format (given by the field `format`).

You can directly modify this pixel array if `SDL_MUSTLOCK(surface)` is false. Otherwise, you need to lock the surface beforehand and unlock it afterwards, using [`SDL_LockSurface`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LockSurface) (and `SDL_UnlockSurface`).

More information can be found in the [`SDL_Surface` page](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface). Taking the remark into consideration, the `pixels` field is read-only if the surface has been optimized for RLE acceleration. Otherwise, it should be fine to modify the pixels directly.